# Update a composite component?

Tags: java, ajax, jsf, composite-component

how can I tell a composite component that it should update another cc?

I tried to give a "update" attribute to the first cc, which is handed to a button.
Then I annotated the snd cc with that id.
Obviously the id is also found, because I can launch the the page already.

BUT clicking the button: nothing happens!

input cc:

```
<composite:interface>
<composite:attribute name="update"/>
</composite:interface>

<composite:implementation>
<p:commandButton value="Create" update="#{cc.attrs.update}" action="register...">
</composite:implementation>
```

JSF:

```
<cc:myInput update=":myDataTable">

<cc:myDataTable id="myDataTable">
```

Anyone has a clue how to do proper update of the cc datatable of within the cc input form button?

thnx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've specified a client ID which starts with `:`, so it will be interpreted relative to the view root (i.e. it becomes the "absolute" client ID). But you seem to have another `NamingContainer` component between the view root and the datatable component, for example a `<h:form>`. Its ID will also end up in the client ID.

To figure the right client ID of the `myDataTable`, you need to open the page in the webbrowser, rightclick and *View Source* and locate the `<table id="xxx:myDataTable">` component where `xxx` is unknown right now. You need to use exactly this client ID in the `update`:

```html
<cc:myInput update=":xxx:myDataTable">
```

Comment: Well, the inside of the myDataTable looks like this:

`<composite:implementation>
<h:panelGroup>
<h:form>
<p:dataTable>
`

The sourcecode I'm getting is something with "auto generated id's", so I cannot reference to them in any case :(


`<form enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" action="/index.jsf" method="post" name="myDataTable:j_idt40" id="myDataTable:j_idt40">

<div class="ui-datatable ui-widget" id="myDataTable:j_idt40:j_idt42">
<table role="grid">
<thead><tr><th colspan="5" class="ui-datatable-header ui-widget-header">Table Header</th></tr><tr role="row">`

Comment: (sorry I cannot do linebreaks here...)

Comment: Just use fixed IDs then? `<h:form id="form">` and so on.

Comment: ok I wrapped my whole cc inside a panelGroup with specific id. refering to this id my ":myDataTable:myPanelGroup" works!

Comment: You're welcome. You could also just have given the `<h:form>` inside the CC a fixed ID and reference it.